# How to add external HTML file in HTML Code

Tags: html

How to add external HTML file in HTML?

> Main.html ⬇️

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>This is Main HTML page</title>
</head>
<body>

<h1>Main Code</h1>
<p>Main Code</p>

</body>
</html>
```

> External.html ⬇️

```
<Div>This is External Code</Div>
```

Comment: You can use iframe

Comment: @Mohi it lacks some functionality

Comment: Unfortunately, there is no easy way to achieve this.